# How to write Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, axapta, x++

Can anyone assist me in writing Unit Tests in AX. Points like

1. What are the conditions that i need to cover
2. What are asserts.

And all basic things that should be kept in mind while writing test class.

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Unit Test` in AX, take a look here:

- [David Pokluda's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dpokluda/archive/tags/systest/)
- [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Unit_Testing)

What conditions do you need to cover? Well, depends, but you should probably aim high on [test coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_coverage).

[Assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) are conditions you would consider true like:

```
this.assertEquals(10, 7+3);
```

Usually you would test variable or return values.